# Error compiling java with imported classes from a jar

Tags: java, jar, import, classpath, javac

I'm having trouble compiling my Java source file on Linux. My source file (PetersTeam.java) imports classes from a jar stored in the same file location as the source. I'm getting errors stating that the packages containing the classes do not exist. I've tried many different variations of the command below I found online, but none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
javac -cp testjar.jar PetersTeam.java
```

Here are my imports which match the package structure in the jar:

```
import org.gamelink.game.Cram;
import org.gamelink.game.Algo;
```

Here are the errors:

```
PetersTeam.java:1: error: package org.gamelink.game does not exist
import org.gamelink.game.Cram;
                    ^
PetersTeam.java:2: error: package org.gamelink.game does not exist
import org.gamelink.game.Algo;
                    ^
```

UPDATE:
with the jar tvf testjar.jar command I am only getting:

```
     0 Tue Jul 14 11:17:46 EDT 2015 META-INF/
    68 Tue Jul 14 11:17:46 EDT 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

so I'm assuming I did something wrong when making the jar here is the command I used , Is there something wrong with it?

```
jar -cvf testjar.jar *.class
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `jar` file (`jar tvf testjar.jar`)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I updated the post, with the results of the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is with the way you created your jar file - assuming you did it at the root of your class hierarchy (which you should) you should have used:

```
jar -cvf testjar.jar org/gamelink/game/*.class
```

... as there shouldn't *any* class flies in the directory in which you're running `jar`.

Comment: Will this work if I have classes in other packages such as org/gamelink/connect ?

Comment: @mysteryhobo: No - you basically need to specify all the class files, or use something like Ant to build it for you. If you're on Unix you could use `find -name '*.class'` to find the class files.

Answer (score 0):

I was have this issue in my application. When I trying to compiling .java file. Answer - my .java file have a many dependency from another classes in my project, and I will must to -  first compiling other classes, and second  - start compiling my goal file(class)